# What is the SQL Statement to delete all entries of an ID after a certain activity occurs?

Tags: sql, vertica

I am struggling with the Vertica SQL Statement to delete all entries of an OrderID after a certain event had occurred.

This is a representation of my data.

```
**OrderID     Activity**  
1             Item Started  
1             Task 1 complete  
1             In storage  
1             Deletion   
1             Deletion Complete  
2             Item Started  
2             Deletion  
2             Deletion Complete
```

In this scenario, I would like to delete the entries "Deletion" and "Deletion Complete" of the OrderID 1, since they occur after the activity "In storage". I want to keep all entries of OrderID 1 until (and including) "In Storage".

For OrderID 2 this is not the case, therefore I want to keep it.

Comment: Do you have a date column ? how do you know the order of the operations ? Queries that do not contain an ORDER BY clause are presented in a way that is easier for the database (usually clustered indexes) which is not deterministic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your situation is exactly as you described it - and you indeed have no relevant timestamps, to check what happened before and what happened later - then you can delete all rows whose activity is either 'Deletion' or 'Deletion Complete' and whose orderid is equal to any order id of any rows that have an activity of 'In storage'.

If, however, 'In storage' needs to happen before 'Deletion' or 'Deletion Complete', then you also need to verify that in the subselect I'm using below.

```
-- create the example table - drop any table of that name existing before ...
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS input;
CREATE TABLE input(OrderID,Activity) AS (
          SELECT 1,'Item Started'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Task 1 complete'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'In storage'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Deletion'
UNION ALL SELECT 1,'Deletion Complete'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Item Started'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Deletion'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'Deletion Complete'
);
-- here goes 
DELETE
FROM  input
WHERE orderid IN (
  SELECT orderid FROM input WHERE activity='In storage'
)
  AND activity IN('Deletion','Deletion Complete')
;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can delete in two steps 1st delete all the records where 'In storage' not available

```
 DELETE FROM table t1 WHERE 
 not exists ( select 1 from table t2 where t1.id=t2.id
                                 and Activity in ('In storage')
 )
```

second step where 'In storage' available

```
DELETE FROM table t1 where activity in('Deletion','Deletion Complete')
```